# Update materialized view in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I want to update materialized view every 5 min such that it does a delta update not a full update. Can i use last modified date, and just update data that has been updated? my question is:

1) how to do update every 5 minute?

2) how to do just a delta import(update) so that it only updates the modified stuff and not go into the whole database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for here is a scheduled fast refresh, which requires a materialised view log on the master tables and which is subject to certain conditions (described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm)).

Whether your MV is suitable for this or not depends on the query that defines it.